# Stop typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types to be applied on vue component not using Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-eslint

I'm using `vue` and I just updated `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.10.1"`. My project contains several components. Some of them are using `javascript` and others `typescript`.

#### Warning

I have this warning for methods inside **non** `typescript` components

> warning: Missing return type on function (@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types)

#### Question

How could I not apply this rule on `.vue` file which are not using `<script lang="ts">` ?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It seems to be a limitation of the `eslint-plugin-vue` plugin -- it applies Typescript rules to both Vue javascript `<script>` *vs.* Typescript `<script lang="ts"` Single File Components.

It's regrettable that we cannot get clean eslint output when reusing such mixed components from elsewhere.

Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 24):

So, the purpose of this rule is to ensure exported modules have a clear interface to whomever uses it externally. From the [rule page](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md), it seems to make sense to use for `.ts` files instead of `.vue` files, but you can judge from your project needs.

For my project, I have used the [suggested `overrides` configuration](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/explicit-module-boundary-types.md#configuring-in-a-mixed-jsts-codebase):

```
{
  "rules": {
    // disable the rule for all files
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      // enable the rule specifically for TypeScript files
      "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": ["error"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Other than that, I don't think you can have `filters` for saying `on the caught .vue files by eslint, only apply the rule on the ones matched by: 'having <script lang="ts">'`.

Maybe you're better off using [inline comments](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) for these specifics errors.

**Edit**

Another solution I see could be to manually list your files on a `.eslint.config` file.

**See Also**

- [Extending your TypeScript linting with Type-Aware Rules](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/README.md#type-aware-rules)
- [I get errors telling me "The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided"](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/docs/linting/TYPED_LINTING.md#i-get-errors-telling-me-the-file-must-be-included-in-at-least-one-of-the-projects-provided)

> If you do want to lint the file with type-aware linting:
> Check the include option of each of the tsconfigs that you provide to parserOptions.project - you must ensure that all files match an include glob, or else our tooling will not be able to find it.
> If your file shouldn't be a part of one of your existing tsconfigs (for example, it is a script/tool local to the repo), then consider creating a new tsconfig (we advise calling it tsconfig.eslint.json) in your project root which lists this file in its include. For an example of this, you can check out the configuration we use in this repo:
> tsconfig.eslint.json
> .eslintrc.js