# ESLint: ignore warning rules

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint

The typescript files are filled with warning symbols and I am trying to ignore the following rules inside the .eslintrc.json file:

1. I want to allow the any type
2. I want to ignore setting void behind functions that are not returning anything.

These are the corresponding warnings:

1. Argument 'myArgument' should be typed.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-
   boundary-types
2. Missing return type on function.eslint@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types

Is there a way to ignore these rules and make the warning disappear?

Answer (score 3):

For `any`, you can use `"no-explicit-any":false`

For `void`, you can use `"no-void": false`

For your other warnings, the eslint rule is `explicit-module-boundary-types`

You probably need

```
 "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off"
```

see

[Stop typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types to be applied on vue component not using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609709/stop-typescript-eslint-explicit-module-boundary-types-to-be-applied-on-vue-compo)

Comment: Thanks @JFPicard I added the rules but the warnings still do not disappear. Please see the updated question with the warnings. Are there different rule for these warnings?